# What does $\int_a^b x dx$ represent?

Tags: calculus

For a planar region $R$, the  $x$ coordinate of centroid is given by the double integral $$\frac1A\iint\limits_R x~dA $$

Similarly is there any geometric significance for the single integral $$\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b x\,dx$$

Comment: I think you forgot $\frac1A$ in the front. That makes a huge difference.

Comment: Ahh right. Fixing.. thx:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac1{b-a}\int\limits_a^bxdx=\frac1{b-a}\cdot\frac12(b^2-a^2)$$$$=\frac{b+a}2$$This is the centroid of the region $[a,b]$.

Comment: Oh it's just the midpoint. Though simple it's interesting as I never looked at this way..

Comment: something like taking the average of arithmetic progression
 $$\dfrac{a + (a+d) + (a+2d)+\cdots +a+(n-1)d}{n} = \dfrac{a+b}{2}$$

Comment: your answer is perfect the way it is @Don Thousand thank you so much:)